# jQuery: Dynamically show and hide select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the user to be able to make a new selection when he clicks on a word. I have already worked on a code which is almost perfect:

http://jsfiddle.net/24rjN/

**HTML:**

```
<p>Your current town of stay:</p>

<p id="profile_town_selected">Vienna</p>

<select id="profile_town_dropdown" style="display:none">
        <option selected="true" style="display:none;">select town</option>
    <option>Barcelona</option>
    <option>London</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
function showOptions(old_selection, dropdown) {
    old_selection.hide();
    dropdown.show();
    dropdown.on('change', function() {
        var new_selection = $(this).val();
        $(this).hide();
        old_selection.text(new_selection).show();
    });
}

$('#profile_town_selected').on('click', function() {
        var old_selection = $(this);
        var dropdown = $('#profile_town_dropdown');
        showOptions(old_selection, dropdown);
    });
```

**My problem:**
The select menu does not disappear when the user decides to stick to the current selection.  When the user for example has clicked on Vienna, then the select menu shows up. If he clicks on Vienna again, the select menu does not disappear. It only disappears when he chooses a town different to the current selection. How do I need to modify the code in order to achieve that the select menu disappears also when the user spontaneously decides not to choose another town?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
    dropdown = $('#profile_town_dropdown');
clickCount = 0;
previousValue = '';
dropdown.on('click', function (event) {
    if (clickCount == 0) {
        clickCount++;
        return;
    } else {
        if ($(this).val() == previousValue) {
            $(this).hide();
            var new_selection = $(this).val();
            old_selection.text(new_selection).show();
            clickCount = 0;
        }
    }
    console.log(event);
});
dropdown.on('change', function () {
    var new_selection = $(this).val();
    $(this).hide();
    previousValue = new_selection;
    old_selection.text(new_selection).show();
}).focus();

$('#profile_town_selected').on('click', function () {
    old_selection = $(this);
    old_selection.hide();
    dropdown.show();
});
$('#profile_town_dropdown').on('blur', function () {
    old_selection.show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/24rjN/1/

Comment: thank you, but this is not quite what i wanted. i do not want the select menu to stay after the user has clicked an option - i want it to disappear immediately, also when the user clicks the same option that already appears before in the <p>-tag

Answer (score 0):

Change `dropdown.on('change', function()` to `dropdown.on('blur', function()`

Try this:

```
function showOptions(old_selection, dropdown) {
        old_selection.hide();
        dropdown.show();
        dropdown.on('blur', function() {
            var new_selection = $(this).val();
            $(this).hide();
            old_selection.text(new_selection).show();
        });
    }

$('#profile_town_selected').on('click', function() {
            var old_selection = $(this);
            var dropdown = $('#profile_town_dropdown');
            showOptions(old_selection, dropdown);
        });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24rjN/2/)**

Comment: thank you, but this is not quite what i wanted. i do not want the select menu to stay after the user has clicked an option - i want it to disappear immediately, also when the user clicks the same option that already appears before in the <p>-tag